# Create view from tables with generalization relationship

Tags: sql, database, oracle

SQL newbie here and I need help with a complex(?) view for my assignment. It's a database which allows teachers to set the grades and number of times a student was absent, for each class the teacher is responsible.

My tables are:

```
USERS (user_id, name, surname)
STUDENTS(student_id (fk to users.user_id), student_number number)
TEACHERS(teacher_id (fk to users.user_id), title varchar2)
CLASSES(class_id, subject, teacher_id(fk to teacher.teacher_id)
CLASS_REGISTRATION(class_id (fk to classes.class_id), student_id (fk to students.student_id), grade, absent_number)
```

I am trying to create two views. One where the student can see the `class.subject`, `class.teacher`, `class_registration.grade`, `class_registration.absent_number`, for every class he has registered.

The other view is for the teachers where they can view, student name, class subject, grade, absent_number, for every class the teacher is responsible.

The generalisation of users -> students, teachers is required and that's what's mostly giving me problems.

EDIT: Here is a query I wrote which seems to give the desired result for the teacher view, I am not sure it the best way though

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "TEACHER_VIEW" ("NAME", "SURNAME", "SUBJECT", "GRADE", "ABSENT") AS 
select u.name, u.surname, c.class, r.grade, r.abstent
from users u, class_registration r, students s, class c
where u.user_id = s.student_id
and s.student_id = r.student_id
and c.class_id = r.class_id
/
```

/

Comment: Show us your attempt at creating these views.  We want to see some SQL, even if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving you the create view statement but here are some links for you which can help you to learn view and it's related concept.

[first](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-view.html)

[second](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj15446.html)

And go through these links and as it's your assignment so try to do it by yourself.

And if you face any problems post here.